# RSpec tests fail because date in SQLite is one day ahead than the system date

Tags: sqlite, rspec

I have a test that checks to see if an item was shipped today.

```
let(:todays_date) {I18n.l(Date.today, format: '%m/%d/%Y')}          
expect(order.shipped_date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")).to eq(todays_date)
```

This test fails with the following error:

> Failure/Error: expect(order.shipped_date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")).to eq(todays_date)
>
> expected: "10/14/2014"
>        got: "10/15/2014"

When I check the date in SQLite is one day ahead than the system date.

```
sqlite> select date('now');
2014-10-15
sqlite> .exit
u2@u2-VirtualBox:~/tools/$ date
Tue Oct 14 20:13:03 EDT 2014
```

I appreciate any help you can provide.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) says:

> Universal Coordinated Time (UTC) is used.

To get the time in the local time zone, use the `localtime` modifier:

```
select date('now', 'localtime');
```

Comment: Thanks @CL! Do you know how I would get the localtime through Rails ActiveRecord. I tried order.shipped_date('localtime') and that seems to fail.

Comment: Try it as second parameter to `strftime`, but I don't know if Rails supports these modifiers.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @CL, I resolved this. I now select all dates in UTC so that they compare.

```
let(:todays_date) {I18n.l(Time.now.utc, format: '%m/%d/%Y')}
```